# Trying to update a field conditionally in SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that populates two sets of application information into the same fields. First the fields are filled out with applicable accounts from group "A" and then the same process happens for group "B" accounts.

Most of the group B fields are filled in by a insert/select statement. However, the query to select "account number" is a little more complex and that is in an UPDATE statement. I will paste the code below but I cannot get it to properly update the rows (for group B) with account numbers, despite the fact the query works on its own outside the procedure (essentially, the account numbers do exist).

Any idea why? I tried adding a case statement to single out group B rows (the where clause is hardcoded for group B... e.g. clfcode = 3) but that didn't work. Let me know if you need more information. I haven't much experience with update statements in stored procedures.

```
update src
        set account_key = case when src.clfcode = 3 and src.branch_key = 12 then a.account_key else src.account_key end
        from @src_table src
        inner join SDFDW_Landing.cu.FICS_ms_Investor_Loan l
        on l.loan_id = src.application_number
        left join dm.dim_product p
        on p.product_key = src.product_key
        left join (
                Select Distinct t.PARENTACCOUNT, t.USERCHAR1 as loan_id
                from SDFDW_Landing.dbo.tracking t
                where t.TYPE = 1
                and t.ProcessDate = @v_max_last_processed_date
                and t.USERCHAR1 is not null
                ) t on t.loan_id = l.loan_id
        left join dm.dim_account a
        on t.PARENTACCOUNT = a.account_nkey
    WHERE p.bdw_report_category = 'Mortgage'
      and l.processdate = @v_max_last_processed_date
```

Comment: Are you **sure** that `src` is uniquely joined to only a single row of all the inner and left joins, because otherwise there is no guarantee as to which result will update `src`

Answer (score 0):

The join on a subquery might cause the issue. You could try to replace it with an apply and see if that helps.

```
update
   src 
set
   account_key = 
   case
      when
         src.clfcode = 3 
         and src.branch_key = 12 
      then
         a.account_key 
      else
         src.account_key 
   end
from
   @src_table src 
   inner join
      SDFDW_Landing.cu.FICS_ms_Investor_Loan l 
      on l.loan_id = src.application_number 
   left join
      dm.dim_product p 
      on p.product_key = src.product_key 
      outer apply ( 
          Select
             acc.* 
          from
             dm.dim_account acc 
             inner join
                SDFDW_Landing.dbo.tracking t 
                on acc.account_nkey = t.parentaccount 
          where
             t.TYPE = 1 
             and t.ProcessDate = @v_max_last_processed_date 
             and t.USERCHAR1 is not null 
             and t.loan_id = l.loan_id 
        ) a 
      WHERE
         p.bdw_report_category = 'Mortgage' 
         and l.processdate = @v_max_last_processed_date
```

alternatively since you are already within a stored procedure, I'd populate a temp table with the data from your subquery and simply join on that temp table from your update statement.